# Ctrl Click to follow Link in Windows Terminal and ZSH

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've just finished setting up ZSH on Windows Terminal. However, I can't for the life of me figure out how to enable the CTRL + Click to follow a link. Eg: When I launch Jupyter Notebook in a directory, to make the URL `http://localhost:8888` clickable so that it directly opens the link in the browser.

[image]

Is there some setting that I can change in the profiles.json or some plugin for ZSH that I can install that will allow me to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think it's a zsh problem, probably more a terminal emulator feature.

Comment: on v2 roadmap: https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/blob/master/doc/terminal-v2-roadmap.md